# How to export additional columns which is calculated

Tags: json, shell, sh, jq

I'm trying to solve this with jq for json.

now my command is just like this below

```
curl -s 'https://api.test-foo.com' \ |  jq -r '.[0:4]|[@csv ' > lineJSON.csv;
```

Then it exports lineJSON.csv successfully and the contents of it is just like this.

```
1656118800000   6.41    6.54    6.37    6.49
1656122400000   6.49    6.49    6.37    6.41
1656126000000   6.4     6.49    6.4     6.46
1656129600000   6.46    6.49    6.41    6.45
1656133200000   6.46    6.69    6.43    6.62
```

Now I want the average price column of 2nd and 3rd columns in the end of each row
(For the 1st row, 6.455 should be added in the end of row since 6.54 + 6.37 = 12.91 / 2 = 6.455)
and
I also want 1st column(Unix Time) to be changed to our local timestamp(Tokyo UTC+9)
just like this style `2022/06/25 10:00:00`

Anyone can show me how to modify my code to add "Average price" and "DateTimeTokyo" in the end of each row?

*Input* This is original JSON

```json
[
  [
    1656057600000,
    "6.34000000",
    "6.46000000",
    "6.32000000",
    "6.40000000",
    "357905.78000000",
    1656061199999,
    "2288895.56780000",
    4948,
    "159142.65000000",
    "1019093.46560000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656061200000,
    "6.40000000",
    "6.43000000",
    "6.32000000",
    "6.36000000",
    "289049.78000000",
    1656064799999,
    "1843763.98200000",
    3894,
    "118557.64000000",
    "756429.84070000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656064800000,
    "6.36000000",
    "6.37000000",
    "6.29000000",
    "6.37000000",
    "285129.01000000",
    1656068399999,
    "1807541.57600000",
    3334,
    "103341.13000000",
    "655180.37320000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656068400000,
    "6.37000000",
    "6.48000000",
    "6.35000000",
    "6.41000000",
    "518232.95000000",
    1656071999999,
    "3324943.41850000",
    5783,
    "238676.31000000",
    "1531735.31810000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656072000000,
    "6.41000000",
    "6.50000000",
    "6.36000000",
    "6.41000000",
    "433692.04000000",
    1656075599999,
    "2792577.58310000",
    4879,
    "208006.61000000",
    "1338394.97480000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656075600000,
    "6.41000000",
    "6.46000000",
    "6.38000000",
    "6.38000000",
    "331641.55000000",
    1656079199999,
    "2129404.72680000",
    3572,
    "129553.56000000",
    "832084.11410000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656079200000,
    "6.39000000",
    "6.46000000",
    "6.31000000",
    "6.33000000",
    "367138.99000000",
    1656082799999,
    "2345811.81770000",
    4138,
    "155818.18000000",
    "996639.28720000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656082800000,
    "6.33000000",
    "6.34000000",
    "6.25000000",
    "6.32000000",
    "277765.44000000",
    1656086399999,
    "1748712.60040000",
    3229,
    "105937.04000000",
    "667653.50140000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656086400000,
    "6.31000000",
    "6.34000000",
    "6.21000000",
    "6.33000000",
    "292571.62000000",
    1656089999999,
    "1838415.38530000",
    3322,
    "125106.86000000",
    "786627.83740000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656090000000,
    "6.33000000",
    "6.39000000",
    "6.30000000",
    "6.32000000",
    "256547.72000000",
    1656093599999,
    "1629535.25120000",
    3111,
    "142450.25000000",
    "905145.04640000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656093600000,
    "6.31000000",
    "6.37000000",
    "6.29000000",
    "6.36000000",
    "145670.56000000",
    1656097199999,
    "922043.36350000",
    1874,
    "64248.58000000",
    "406818.31590000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656097200000,
    "6.36000000",
    "6.43000000",
    "6.33000000",
    "6.41000000",
    "166864.05000000",
    1656100799999,
    "1065420.11920000",
    2283,
    "91270.24000000",
    "582815.21460000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656100800000,
    "6.42000000",
    "6.47000000",
    "6.39000000",
    "6.41000000",
    "263666.61000000",
    1656104399999,
    "1694938.34150000",
    2981,
    "134116.12000000",
    "862431.12740000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656104400000,
    "6.41000000",
    "6.58000000",
    "6.39000000",
    "6.49000000",
    "333943.30000000",
    1656107999999,
    "2173180.47910000",
    3467,
    "173197.33000000",
    "1127178.67370000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656108000000,
    "6.48000000",
    "6.59000000",
    "6.47000000",
    "6.48000000",
    "275831.12000000",
    1656111599999,
    "1799221.74850000",
    3021,
    "135880.84000000",
    "886416.11690000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656111600000,
    "6.48000000",
    "6.58000000",
    "6.45000000",
    "6.58000000",
    "212810.34000000",
    1656115199999,
    "1384445.00940000",
    2780,
    "100044.84000000",
    "651205.64950000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656115200000,
    "6.58000000",
    "6.80000000",
    "6.39000000",
    "6.41000000",
    "1132685.69000000",
    1656118799999,
    "7446281.09020000",
    13348,
    "550911.19000000",
    "3625786.19610000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656118800000,
    "6.41000000",
    "6.54000000",
    "6.37000000",
    "6.49000000",
    "222382.87000000",
    1656122399999,
    "1436781.15290000",
    3073,
    "115733.77000000",
    "747659.36930000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656122400000,
    "6.49000000",
    "6.49000000",
    "6.37000000",
    "6.41000000",
    "175230.64000000",
    1656125999999,
    "1123960.98650000",
    2096,
    "82402.98000000",
    "529043.58300000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656126000000,
    "6.40000000",
    "6.49000000",
    "6.40000000",
    "6.46000000",
    "82505.41000000",
    1656129599999,
    "532169.91250000",
    1568,
    "42924.41000000",
    "276746.49050000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656129600000,
    "6.46000000",
    "6.49000000",
    "6.41000000",
    "6.45000000",
    "94275.69000000",
    1656133199999,
    "608332.20580000",
    1543,
    "45898.91000000",
    "296161.88110000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656133200000,
    "6.46000000",
    "6.69000000",
    "6.43000000",
    "6.54000000",
    "471454.85000000",
    1656136799999,
    "3099237.66700000",
    6029,
    "248054.66000000",
    "1630171.24030000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656136800000,
    "6.54000000",
    "6.55000000",
    "6.46000000",
    "6.51000000",
    "225240.12000000",
    1656140399999,
    "1464238.69720000",
    3053,
    "100045.45000000",
    "650888.68290000",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1656140400000,
    "6.51000000",
    "6.61000000",
    "6.51000000",
    "6.52000000",
    "233901.49000000",
    1656143999999,
    "1537312.84570000",
    2919,
    "119864.29000000",
    "787784.96020000",
    "0"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `jq -r '.[] | .[:5] | @tsv'` produced your original output, try changing it to

```bash
jq -r '
  .[] | .[:5]
  | .[0] |= (./1000 | strflocaltime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
  | .[2,3] |= tonumber
  | .[5] = (.[2] + .[3]) / 2
  | @tsv
'
```

This updates column `0` by dividing it by 1000 to turn milliseconds into seconds, then applying `strflocaltime` with your desired format.
Then it updates columns `2` and `3` to turn them into numbers, as then they are used to calculate column `5` by adding them up and dividing the sum by 2.

Note: I supposed your original filter as having `.[]`, `.[0:5]` and `@tsv` instead of only `.[0:4]` and `@csv`, as your input is wrapped in another array, and the output shown had five columns, not four, and was separated by tabs, not commas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got this error back "jq: error (at <stdin>:0): array ([1656118800...) and number (1000) cannot be divided"

Comment: @MKK Please show the output of the `curl` command (without invoking `jq`) to see the original format. (You can edit your question, and provide it as "input" to your `jq` call, thus replacing the `curl` command altogether, as it is irrelevant to the question)

Comment: @MKK Thank you, but by "output" I meant the JSON document that is output by `curl` and fed into `jq`, not the command you are using

Comment: oops...my bad! I updated again!

Comment: @MKK I updated my answer as well, adding `.[]` at the beginning as you are inputting an array, and adding `| .[2,3] |= tonumber` before calculating the average, to convert the columns to numbers as they are input as strings.